# Need to join in parenthesis in picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={midway}]
  \matrix[column sep={4em,between origins}, row sep={2em}] at (0,0) {

    \node(A) {$A$}  ; & \node(B) {$B$}; \\

    \node(C) {$C$}  ; & \node (D) {$D$};\\
  };
  \draw[<-] (C) -- (D) node[anchor=east]{};

  \draw[->] (A) -- (B) node[anchor=south] {};

  \draw[->] (B) -- (D) node[anchor=west] {};

  \draw[->] (C) -- (D) node[anchor=north] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here, I am trying to replace `$A$` by `$A(X)$` and `$B$` by `$B(Y)$` but it does not work. Could you please suggest me some way to get this.

Comment: By indenting your code by 4 spaces it gets formatted in a readable way. For inline code like `$A$` put backticks around it as in `\`$A$\``

Comment: Could you please add an image where you mark the problem? (A simple screenshot and edits with paint / gimp are ok)

Comment: I don't get your question. What is the problem when you replace $A$ by $A(X)$? Seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: Thank you Bordaigorl, Moose and Maarten. I am doing as Bordaigorl suggestion and it seems going to work. But still the symbol ` appear in figure.  @ Maarten Dhondt, the problem is if I add $A(X)$ then it was not working before.

Comment: Bordaigorl's comment was just about formatting your posts here on TeX.SX, it was not meant for use in your actual figure.

Comment: Also, if I edit your code so that I have `\node(A) {$A(X)$}  ; & \node(B) {$B(Y)$};` instead of `\node(A) {$A$}  ; & \node(B) {$B$};`  in the matrix it works just fine, how does that not work for you?

Comment: Thank you all. Finally, I used the Torbjorn idea and it is working.

Comment: @Rajesh In `\node(A){$A$}` the first `A` is just a label and it could be anything. The node text is what's in braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For commutative diagrams, I'd suggest you to use the powerful and versatile [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package:

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A(x)\ar{r} & B(y)\ar{d} \\
C\ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    A(x) & \rightarrow & B(y)       \\
         &             & \downarrow \\
    C    & \rightarrow & D
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note: This looks of course best if the elements in the diagram have approximately the same width.

Answer (score 1):

With tkz-graph :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
      % Verices
  \SetGraphUnit{4} % 4 cm between each nodes except local changes
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Empty] % only label and no drawing around nodes
  \SetVertexMath % all the labels are in math mode

  \Vertex[L=A(x)]{a}        \EA[L=B(y)](a){b} 
  \SO[L=C,,unit=2](a){c}        \SO[L=D,unit=2](b){d} % unit = 2 change the distance 

      % Edges
  \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style = {->}} % style of edges
  \Edges (a,b,d)     \Edges (c,d)  

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all. How do I give the inclusion arrow between $A$ to $C$ ?